# Нестандартная форма с зависимыми радиокнопками

Tags: javascript, html

Существует форма внутри таблицы:

```
          Begin    End     List    Done

   0      1900     1900    ...     Yes

   0      2015     2015    ...     Yes

   0      2016     2016    ...     Yes
```

Где - 
0 - радиокнопка;

Begin - текстовое поле

End   - текстовое поле

List  - выпадающий список

Done  - checkbox

Можно ли организовать такую форму, что бы при отправке отправлялись данные только той строки где выбрано radio.

Вот примерный код, только сильно не ругайте.

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <table cellspacing="0" width="640px">
    <tr class="t-head">
      <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">Begin</td>
      <td width="25%">End</td>
      <td width="30%">List</td>
      <td>Done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input checked name="id" type="radio" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="beg" size="4" value="1900">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="end" size="4" value="1900">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" name="list">
          <option selected value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="otm" type="checkbox" value="1" /><b>Yes</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="id" type="radio" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="beg" size="4" value="2015">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="end" size="4" value="2015">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" name="list">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option selected value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input checked name="otm" type="checkbox" value="1" /><b>Yes</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="id" type="radio" value="3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="beg" size="4" value="2016">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="end" size="4" value="2016">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" name="list">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option selected value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="otm" type="checkbox" value="1" /><b>Yes</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Народ есть какие нибудь идеи, или такие формы не возможно реализовать

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj = {};

function radioCheked() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("id");
  var val;
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      var row = radios[i].parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('input');
      var select = radios[i].parentElement.parentElement.querySelector(".list");
      var indexSelect = select.selectedIndex;
      obj.Begin = row[1].value;
      obj.End = row[2].value;
      obj.List = select.options[indexSelect].text;
      obj.Done = row[3].checked;

    }
  }
  console.log(obj)
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <table cellspacing="0" width="640px">
    <tr class="t-head">
      <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="25%">Begin</td>
      <td width="25%">End</td>
      <td width="30%">List</td>
      <td>Done</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row'>
      <td>
        <input checked name="id" type="radio" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="beg" size="4" value="1900">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="end" size="4" value="1900">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class='list' size="1" name="list">
          <option selected value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="otm" type="checkbox" value="1" /><b>Yes</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row'>
      <td>
        <input name="id" type="radio" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="beg" size="4" value="2015">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="end" size="4" value="2015">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class='list' size="1" name="list">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option selected value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input checked name="otm" type="checkbox" value="1" /><b>Yes</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row'>
      <td>
        <input name="id" type="radio" value="3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="beg" size="4" value="2016">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="end" size="4" value="2016">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class='list' size="1" name="list">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option selected value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>

        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="otm" type="checkbox" value="1" /><b>Yes</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" onclick="radioCheked();">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Извините меня, но я как раз таки не умею собирать (

Comment: @Xfirab добавил...

Comment: если я в  action напишу например test.php, то он эти данные отправить на сервер, или отправка на сервер по другому реализуется

Comment: @Xfirab неа. пишите свою функцию..))

Comment: Эх, что то слишком сложно выходит ((

Comment: @Xfirab работа такая...)))

Comment: Тогда можете написать эту функцию для отправки на сервер (test.php)

Comment: @Xfirab тренируйтесь:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: А без ajax нельзя обойтись

Answer (score 1):

Возможно все. Перед отправкой формы нужно просто сделать проверку где стоит радио кнопка, и тогда отправлять данные только той строки. Каждой радио кнопке присвойте идентификатор, и с помощью javascript проверяйте форму перед отправкой.

Comment: А не могли вы примерный код написать, я сам плохо знаю JS

Comment: @Xfirab, могу, ждите

Comment: Abmin а как у Вас, еще не попробовали ?

Comment: @Xfirab, у меня сейчас мало времени

Comment: Вопрос все ещё актуальный